# Accessing parent object from child method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, this

I have a Backbone view as follows:

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    bar: 1,

    open: function() {
        $(window).on('resize', this.resizeHandler);
    },

    close: function() {
        $(window).off('resize', this.resizeHandler);
    },

    resizeHandler: function(e) {
        alert(this.bar);
    }
});
```

this.bar fails in the resizeHandler method because 'this' is no longer a reference to the parent object, but to the event/html element related to the event.

How can I get this to work so that resizeHandler has a reference to the parent object and I still have a reference to a function that I can use in both the Jquery on and off methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [FAQ, entry Binding "this"](http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this)

> Perhaps the single most common JavaScript "gotcha" is the fact that
>   when you pass a function as a callback, its value for `this` is lost.
>   With Backbone, when dealing with events and callbacks, you'll often
>   find it useful to rely on [_.bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) and [_.bindAll](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll) from Underscore.js.

The easiest way to solve your problem is probably to use [_.bindAll](http://underscorejs.org/#bindAll)

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    bar: 1,

    initialize: function() {
       _.bindAll(this, 'resizeHandler');
    },

    open: function() {
        $(window).on('resize', this.resizeHandler);
    },

    close: function() {
        $(window).off('resize', this.resizeHandler);
    },

    resizeHandler: function(e) {
        console.log(this.bar);
    }
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/DZqDw/ (I would advise to avoid `alert` to debug your code, especially when you track mouse movements/resize events)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `bind` (http://backbonejs.org/#FAQ-this) ?

For example:

```
$(window).on('resize', _.bind( this.resizeHandler, this ) );
```

Comment: _bindAll as suggested by nikoshr suits my particular use better, but thanks for the help.

Comment: One problem with `_.bind` in this context is that you have to store the `_.bind` return value somewhere so that you can `$(window).off(...)` it, `_.bindAll` replaces `this.resizeHandler` for you so that problem goes away.